# Web Service (Server - Client). Server uses external project

Tags: java, web-services, client, server, informix

I'm using a Web Service with this structure:

Server:

```
@WebService @HandlerChain(file="handler-chain.xml") @XmlRootElement 

public class RDA_DenegarRenovacion{

HashMapWrapper map =  new HashMapWrapper();


@WebMethod
public String getServerName() {

    return "RDA - DenegarPropuesta";

}

@WebMethod(operationName="pc_ren_propuesta")
@WebResult(name="hashMapWrapper")

public HashMapWrapper pc_ren_propuesta() {

    HashMap<String,String> realMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
    realMap.put("jaja1", "jeje1");
    realMap.put("jaja2", "jeje2");
    map.setRealMap(realMap);

    //I JUST DECLARE THE FACADE AND SERVICE FROM THE IMPORTED PROJECT, 
    //BUT I'M NOT USING THEM YET
    CommonFacade commonFacade = new CommonFacade();
    CommonDataService service = (CommonDataService) commonFacade.commonDataService;


    return map;
}
```

In the server method, I just access another java project in the same workspace (declaring facade and service).

In order to declare classes from another project, I configure the buildpath and I also add the jar commons-discovery-0.2, because if not, I get the error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/discovery/tools/DiscoverSingleton
>       at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.components.logger.LogFactory$2.run(LogFactory.java:144)
>       at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:63)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.components.logger.LogFactory.createLogFactory(LogFactory.java:140)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.components.logger.LogFactory.(LogFactory.java:97)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.xmlsoap.Utils.(Utils.java:49)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.soap.MessageFactoryImpl.(MessageFactoryImpl.java:116)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.soap.SAAJMetaFactoryImpl.newMessageFactory(SAAJMetaFactoryImpl.java:56)
>       at javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.SOAPVersion.(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.SOAPVersion.(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.BindingID.(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createAndPublishEndpoint(Unknown Source)
>       at javax.xml.ws.Endpoint.publish(Unknown Source)
>       at RDA_DenegarRenovacion.publisher.WsPublisher.main(WsPublisher.java:14)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.discovery.tools.DiscoverSingleton
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>       ... 14 more

With all this, I publish the server part, and when running the client, due to the fact I added that external jar, I obtain the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: An attempt was made to insert a node where it is not permitted. 
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAP11Fault.getProtocolException(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at $Proxy29.pcRenPropuesta(Unknown Source)
>       at rda_denegarrenovacion.client.WsClient.main(WsClient.java:21)

If I don't declare any class from the other project and I don't import any jar, it works fine.

**Summary:**

I need the following.

Client --> Server --> Informix Java project --> Server --> Client.

I'm having problems when accessing Informix Java project.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

I set JAVA_HOME and Path variables, and I add external wsgen jar. Restarted computer and it worked.